# Apache on WIndows - growing VM Size of httpd.exe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache

I have a Rails app running with Apache on a Windows 2003 server . I am using the Apache Lounge version of apache.

Httpd.exe process's Mem usage and VM Size is growing constantly and quite fast, while there is not much load. Most alarming is the VM size, as it appears to be growing at a much faster pace, reaching several GB in a couple of days, while Mem usage may reach several hundreds MB during the same period of time. This finally results in the app crashing.

I am trying to find an explanation for the rate of VM size growth and a way to stop it growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried adding 'SSLSessionCache none' to httpd.conf and it solved the problem for me! Now httpd.exe's Mem Usage/VM Size do not seem to grow at all.

Answer (score -1):

This is a normal thing, because the apache moded to Rails do this as a normal thing, but there is a project that reduces this, ModRails: http://www.modrails.com/ , it's the best to use Rails with Apache, but i don't use it, because I'm using Mongrel.

Comment: I am using mongrels too. I am also using ssl. So far the only solution I've found that seems to help is setting MaxRequestsPerChild  so that httpd.exe is restarted upon mem usage reaching a certain size.  I've also heard that when using SSL setting SSLSessionCache to 'none' may help. Haven't tried it yet.